# как получить текст пересланного сообщения aiogram python

Tags: python, aiogram

я переслал боту сообщение, как сделать так, что бы он достал текст из сообщения, которое я переслал ему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом примере функция handle_forwarded_message представляет собой обработчик сообщений, который запускается всякий раз, когда сообщение пересылается боту. Атрибут is_forwarded декоратора message_handler гарантирует, что обработчик вызывается только для переадресованных сообщений.

```
@dp.message_handler(is_forwarded=True)
async def handle_forwarded_message(message: types.Message):
    text = message.text  # получите текст исходного сообщения, которое было переслано
```